# CSS Keyframe Issue

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, keyframe

I created a simple CSS animation. In the fiddle I believe all of the properties are correct but no animation is happening. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong. I am attaching some sample code and the jsfiddle below. Thanks.

```
@-moz-keyframes til {
    0%   { margin-top: -200px; }
    20%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    35%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    50%  { margin-top: -194px; }
    75%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    80%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
@-o-keyframes til {
    0%   { margin-top: -200px; }
    20%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    35%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    50%  { margin-top: -194px; }
    75%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    80%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
@keyframes til {
    0%   { margin-top: -200px; }
    20%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    35%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    50%  { margin-top: -194px; }
    75%  { margin-top: -196px; }
    80%  { margin-top: -198px; }
    100% { margin-top: -200px; }
}
/*-------------------Animation Keyframes------------------------*/

.one {
    z-index: 5;
    -webkit-animation: til 2s ease-in infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation: til 2s ease-in infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation: til 2s ease-in infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation: til 2s ease-in infinite; /* IE 10+ */
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(http://galnova.com/diabetescrush/img/mob/wave.png) no-repeat;        
    background-position: center;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/pnk0j8gv/9/

Comment: Are you applying that only the top item is animating and the other stay still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing in Chrome or Safari? You do have a `-webkit-animation` property, but no `-webkit-keyframes`. Once you add that, things start moving (maybe not correctly, but at least they do).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/pnk0j8gv/12/)

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I forgot the webkit!

Answer (score 1):

First things first..

**You seem to be using inefficiently the `key-fames` system.
There is no need to apply `margin-top` while for your solution the `-webkit-transform:translate(Xpx, Ypx);` will work just fine.**

> `-webkit-transform:translate` will aplly the translation to the current position of your elements, without need to fix the values in keyframes.

Next is compatibility, check this W3 table for e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

**Here is a working example ( tested on mozilla ) with all the elements moving:
http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/pnk0j8gv/14/**

Comment: Wow this is amazing. I am still trying to figure out how you condensed it so much. Thank you!